# Alternating types in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem where I need to display two different types in an items control.  Type A will be represented by a templated radio button and Type B will be represented by an icon where each 'B' type shall only appear between two A types. (i.e. Not at the start or end of the collection.)

I have my `XAML` ready to go complete with selectors, but I'm struggling to get my data configured correctly. I have a populated collection for each type but need to find a way to combine them.  Is there something I am missing in the Composite collection documentation that would allow me to automagically pull one element from collection A then one from B and so on?

Comment: I don't think so. It sounds like you may need to bind to a list of a common base type (possibly even `object`) that has your desired order already set up. CompositeCollection isn't really set up to handle this case.

Comment: That is not a bad idea. The two types have no common base other than object so binding to an instance of 'ObservableCollection<object>'  seems to be a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer, glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no automagical way of doing this with CompositeCollection.

Instead, you will need to bind to a pre-arranged collection of some base class (possibly even `object`) that has the alternating pre-done.